# How can i make my list View Clickable?

Tags: android

> I want to make my list clickable and want to start a new activity but i am unable to click and nothing happens when i click on the list.
>   Please help me to make list view clickable.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_user_events);
        lists = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
        final QueryClass qc = new QueryClass(getApplication());
        qc.open();
        EventName = qc.getUserEventName();
        eventDate = qc.getUserEventDate();
        qc.close();
        CustomClass adapter = new CustomClass(this, EventName, eventDate, deleteButton);
        lists.setAdapter(adapter);

        lists.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(GetUserEvents.this,GetUserFunctions.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Blockquote

Comment: Please post your error log/any logs which is coming in Android Monitor

Comment: Have you included GetUserFunctions activity in your manifest file?

Comment: Are you listening to any click in the adapter.If you are then that listener will override the one you written in this class.

Comment: there is no error...when i click on the list view nothing happens

Comment: Copy paste your complete class here

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
            long arg3) 
      {
       startActivity(new Intent(GetUserEvents.this,GetUserFunctions.class));
      }
   });
```

Comment: if problem persists then show your xml layout. thanks

Answer (score 0):

> here is my complete class.

```
package weddingplanner.countmyapp.com.weddingplanner;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GetUserEvents extends Activity {
ListView lists;
ArrayList<String> EventName = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> eventDate = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> deleteButton = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_user_events);
    lists = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
    final QueryClass qc = new QueryClass(getApplication());
    qc.open();
    EventName = qc.getUserEventName();
    eventDate = qc.getUserEventDate();
    qc.close();
    CustomClass adapter = new CustomClass(this, EventName, eventDate,         deleteButton);
    lists.setAdapter(adapter);

    lists.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int   position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new   Intent(GetUserEvents.this,GetUserFunctions.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: OnItemClickListener is not supported by my android studio.